# Integration using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Can you find, using residue theorem, ($\epsilon >0$), the value of this integral ($I$)?

\begin{equation}
I=\lim_{\epsilon->0^{+}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dw}{w+i\epsilon}
\end{equation}

Thank you very much!

Finally I have proved that its value is $I=-i\pi$ using a semi-circular contour $C=C_{1}+C_{2}$,

$C_{1}: z=x, -R<x<R$

$C_{2}: z=Re^{i\theta}, 0<\theta<\pi$

Supposing that the residue of integrand at $z=-i\epsilon$ is not in $C$ because $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon->0^{+}} \int_{C} \frac{dz}{z+i\epsilon}=I+\lim_{R->\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{iRe^{i\theta} d\theta}{Re^{i\theta}+0}=2\pi i Res(f(z), z\in C)=0$$

and
$$
\lim_{R->\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{iRe^{i\theta} d\theta}{Re^{i\theta}+0}=\int_{0}^{\pi} id\theta=i\pi
$$
Finally,
$$
I=-\lim_{R->\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{iRe^{i\theta} d\theta}{Re^{i\theta}+0}=-i\pi$$

Comment: The integral is divergent in ordinary sense. Do you think of a [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)?

Comment: Yes. I have found that its value is $-\pi i$

Comment: Then I suggest you answer the question yourself and mark it as selected.

Comment: Finally I have found its value (if my computations are correct).

Comment: It is correct to suppose that residue of $\frac{1}{z+iw}$ is zero in $C$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's theorem (no residue involved ($\varepsilon>0$)),
\begin{gather*}
\forall R>0:\int_{-R}^R\frac{dw}{w+i\varepsilon}
   =-i\int_0^{\pi}\frac{Re^{i\varphi}}
{Re^{i\varphi}+i\varepsilon}\,d\varphi\to-i\pi, \quad \varepsilon\to0.\\
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\left[p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dw}{w+i\varepsilon}\right]=\lim_{R\to\infty}\left[\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}
\int_{-R}^R\frac{dw}{w+i\varepsilon}\right]=-i\pi.
\end{gather*}